# "take something back" can be used for describing a perspective or an idea?

Tags: verbs

I know "take something back" means "return something" or "admit what you said was wrong".
But can the phrase "take back" be used with an idea or a perspective?
Let me take an example.

**Many people tend to think design means more money. Once such perspective is firmly set in their minds, taking it back is difficult.**

Comment: Once this kind of perspective is firmly set in their minds, **giving it up** is difficult. [Basically this is editing.] :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the expression "[take something back](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-back?q=take%20something%20back)" to mean "to admit that something you said was wrong", you are using it figuratively to mean that you are taking back the words that you said.

You can't use it to mean that somebody's perspective changes, because it doesn't involve (either literally or figuratively) taking anything back.